# how I upload multiple images in to different ImageView?

Tags: android, xml, image-uploading

I need to upload 2 different image in to different image view. How can I upload?

Here is my xml sample file.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/uivProfileImage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/uivProfileCoverImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/uivProfileImage"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: specify your problem..you can put only static image with this imageview..

Comment: upload from where from server or in app ?

Comment: i have store local path in sharedprefrence and from sahredprefrence show in imageview.  on image click it will ask me to capure image or uplad from gallery and  after click on update button it will upload to server.

Comment: So, where are you having trouble in that? @VasudevM.Vyas

Comment: Set First Image in ImageView using OnActivityResult() after i have to set another image in another imageview . how i can set that image?

Comment: Confused...where do you want to upload 2nd image....in the imageview with first image or the other one?

Comment: i am making update profile so  there are profile pic and coverImage pic that i have to update here.   i want to update profile pic as well as coverpic too.

Comment: hmm....so you want to update both of them.....but update them in one step or two steps?

Comment: it is one step.@DroidWormNarendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `request code` to distinguish which ImageView was clicked, for example

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FIRST_IMAGE);
```

where `PICK_FIRST_IMAGE` is int value equals 100

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_SECOND_IMAGE);
```

where `PICK_SECOND_IMAGE` is int value equals 101.

Then in `onActivityResult` you can do something like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent data) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                ...

                if(requestCode == PICK_FIRST_IMAGE)
                    firstImageView.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                else
                    secondImageView.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
            }
```